# What does the "rectangle with waves" logo to the right of the trackpad mean on my Dell Precision M4700?

Tags: laptop, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision M4700 laptop. But I can't figure out what this thing in the picture is. Can somebody help?

[image: Dell Precision M4700]

Comment: According to the [Dell site](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-m4700/pd) of your model it should have Mobile Broadband & GPS and the picture you're seeing is most likely to indicate that

Comment: For the same of search engine friendlyness, I'd like to point out that looks like a rectangle or card with a radio symbol around it and that it dosen't look much like the official near field communication symbol on the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This icon indicates an [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) reader. It is used for [two-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) using a [contactless smart card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_smart_card) and a password.

This means you can log into your computer by both tapping a smart card to the icon and typing your password, offering added security.  This is often used in corporate environments where high security is required.

For more information, see page 79 (PDF page 50) of [this Dell document](http://partnerdirect.dell.com/sites/channel/Documents/Dell-Precision-M4700-M6700-Mobile-Workstation-Technical-Guidebook.pdf).  The reader supports several NFC protocols, including iCLASS and MIFARE.

Comment: I just tapped my smartphone which has NFC. Nothing happened. :(

Comment: The reader might not be enabled continuously.

Comment: I don't think it is NFC. No such thing appears in Device Manager.

Comment: Look for a smart card reader in Device Manager. Perhaps it is disabled at the BIOS...

Comment: I do use Smart Card Reader on it which is a slot on the left side in which the card slides in. It is "Broadcom usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)". Another is Dell Control Vault with fingerprint swipe sensor which is visible on the right. I will test with my smart card on this logo and update this thread.

Comment: That's for a different type of smart card than what you're using.  You're using a *contact* smart card.  The NFC reader is for *contactless* smart cards.

Comment: Many laptop manufacturers use the same case for different model laptops, even if they don't have all the features.  My Dell has a bunch of labeled but non-functional ports on the sides for features that were not included on this model, basically dummy ports which I could presumably upgrade.

Comment: As far as I know the Dell notebooks do not have NFC integrated. It is a contactless smart card reader. See also the other answers.

Comment: It's built on the same NFC protocols nonetheless.

Comment: I was hoping it was wireless charging.... But yea.. that would be to convenient.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be the [contactless smart card reader](http://ridrix.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/dell-embedded-contactless-smartcard-reader/). It should appear as "Broadcom Unified Security Hub CV w/fingerprint sensor" in the Device Manager.

Comment: There is one "Dell Control Vault with fingerprint swipe sensor". I will test this out.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Contactless Smart Card reader, according to [the manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-e6530_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf) (see p81). No word on NFC in the manual.